# How to store list of foreign keys in a model

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework

Hii Everyone here is the case in which i am facing this same issue please have a look over this:

ClassificationGroup.py

```
class DeviceClassificationGroup:
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    classification = ??
```

Classification.py

```
class DeviceClassification(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    device_type = models.IntegerField()
    device_name_regex = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vid_pid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    device_instance_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So i would have set of classifications that i can put in the one classification group.

How can i store an unknown amount of foreign keys in a django model??

Kindly help me out in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding a `ForeignKey` field to the `DeviceClassification` model:

```py
class DeviceClassification(models.Model):
  group = models.ForeignKey(DeviceClassificationGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='classifications')
```

Remember, that adding a foreign key to a model creates a One-To-Many relationship, meaning that one `DeviceClassification` belongs to *one* `DeviceClassificationGroup`, and a `DeviceClassificationGroup` can have *many* `DeviceClassification` objects associated with it.

If you now want to access your `DeviceClassification` objects from an `DeviceClassificationGroup` instance:

```py
group.classifications.all()
```

Note that the accessor is the same as specified as `related_name` in the model.

If you do not specify a `related_name`, it will be auto-chosen as `<model_name>_set`. If you do not want a related name, you can use `+`.

Docs: [Related Name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Answer (score 0):

i think you might looking for built a relationships between `DeviceClassification` & `DeviceClassificationGroup` where one group may have multiple classification

So just use like this

```
class DeviceClassification(models.Model):
  group = models.ForeignKey(DeviceClassificationGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So after applying this if you run `DeviceClassificationGroup.classification`
you'll get all the classification list

If you want to learn in depth you can check [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)